# Windows phone app with many image - best way?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-8, resources

In my application, there are about 300 images(.jpg). These images are displayed to the user.  I now choose between two options loaded:

1. Loading of resources in isolated storage.
2. Working with resource files directly.

Which of these options is better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using these images as a static data means these 300 images are kind of dataset for your application then second option `Working with resource files directly` is fine. There is no need for isolated storage. It is typically used for data that is generated in your app or downloaded from server and you want to use it for future.
Hope it helps you.